# mysql query to get data corresponding to duplicate records

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, group-concat

this is a table name test1

```
id  Roll Rank Grade
1    10   50   A
2    20   60   B
3    30   40   X
4    20   50   A
5    30   90   O
6    10   80   C
```

want result in following format :

```
id  Roll   Rank    Grade
1    10   50,80     A,C
2    20   60,80     B,A
3    30   40,90     X,O
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```sql
SELECT id, Roll, GROUP_CONCAT(Rank), GROUP_CONCAT(Grade)
FROM your_table
GROUP BY Roll
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT A.id, A.Roll, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(A.Rank ORDER BY A.id) AS Rank, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(A.Grade ORDER BY A.id) AS Grade
FROM test1 A 
GROUP BY A.Roll
ORDER BY A.Roll;
```